# Control parent tableview using ViewWithTag from the subclass of the table header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIView` subclass of a table's header view, is it possible to get the table view from my header view subclass using `viewWithTag:`?  I tried below methods but still get nothing:

my method 1:

```
UIView *tv = (UIView *)[self.superview viewWithTag:11];
```

my method 2:

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)[self.superview viewWithTag:11];
```

Thanks.

Comment: BTW - why do you need the table view from the header view? That shouldn't be necessary. What is your goal?

Comment: you're right, i changed the code to avoid this approach, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to walk the view's superview hierarchy until you get to the table view. This approach will work regardless of the underlying table view structure.

```
UIView *view = self.superview;
UITableView *tv = nil;
while (view) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        tv = (UITableView *)view;
        break;
    }
    view = view.superview;
}

if (tv) {
    // found the table view. Do something with it
}
```

Comment: If this being called after the view has been added to the table?

Answer (score 0):

Create your UITableView:

```
 TableHeaderView *v = [[TableHeaderView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
_tableView.tableHeaderView = v;
// I think you miss this line
_tableView.tag = 101; 
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NSLog(@"%@",_tableView.backgroundColor); 
// value: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
```

In your TableHeaderView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // just example to get super class
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
return self;
}

- (void) doSomething
{
UITableView *tb = (UITableView*) [self.superview viewWithTag:101];
NSLog(@"%@",tb.backgroundColor);
// value: after:UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
}
```